# Remote login into the phone from a PC

Tags: remote-control, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any VNC solutions for an unrooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/any-vnc-solutions-for-an-unrooted-device)

Is it possible to remotely control an Android phone from a PC. Is there a program similar to VNC **server** that runs on the phone, with the client displaying phone's UI on the PC?

When I'm at my desk, it would be much easier to manage the phone (read/type SMS, install apps etc.) from the PC instead of poking the tiny touchscreen.

Searching brings many solutions in the other direction (VNC server on PC, VNC client on phone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, but your phone needs to be rooted: [Droid VNC](http://www.appbrain.com/app/droid-vnc-server/org.onaips.vnc)**

With an unrooted phone and other apps you can do certain things like access the SD card, send SMS messages and manage apps, but to gain total control of the device it needs to be rooted.

See my related inquiries [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/any-vnc-solutions-for-an-unrooted-device) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/any-reverse-vnc-apps-that-dont-require-the-android-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

Team viewer had recently provided app for Samsung phones. After installing this app in, the phone can be remotely accessed from PC.  The following is the screen shot from [its site](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/mobile-app.aspx):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Webkey](http://webkey.cc/) ([Play store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey), [AppBrain link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/webkey-%28root-required%29/com.webkey)) is an open source app for remotely controlling your phone from a web browser.

**Your phone must be rooted** to use Webkey.

Answer (score 0):

On your phone, search the app store for 'TeamViewer Host'. You can then connect from your PC.