# Application or software by which we can access tablet or mobile remotely over internet?

Tags: applications, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any VNC solutions for an unrooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/any-vnc-solutions-for-an-unrooted-device)

I am using TeamViewer and other VPN remote access software to access my laptop or PC from my Android phone. But is there any software by which I can access my Android smartphone remotely over Internet either through Android phone or through laptop.

Comment: See these previous questions: [Any VNC solutions for an unrooted device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/), [Remote login into the phone from a PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/), [How do I access by android phone from web browser and control it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/), and [How to Remote Control Android smartphone, if not in same subnet](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/)

Comment: I want exactly same remote access as we are using for desktop application. mean complete screen of the tablet or phone should apprear in PC or laptop. So I can get feel as I am working on my tablet only. mean playing on tablet without having tablet on hand.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote Phone Access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goupilapps.remoteaccessandroid&hl=en) from Google Play Store does what you want.

Comment: I want exactly same remote access as we are using for desktop application. mean complete screen of the tablet or phone should apprear in PC or laptop. So I can get feel as I am working on my tablet only. mean playing on tablet without having tablet on hand..