# How to avoid rooting my phone?

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any VNC solutions for an unrooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/any-vnc-solutions-for-an-unrooted-device)

I want to connect my phone to my computer via USB, and be able to send keystrokes to phone, and send phone's video output to computer screen. It's easy, i check out several tutorials, but i DON'T want to root my phone, i don't want to void my warranty. Is there ANY way to send keystrokes to Android phone from any "third-party" device, or to send phone's video output to computer without rooting the phone?

Comment: It depends entirely on your particular phone, version of Android, etc.

Comment: But, i can't generally create an application that would work with any android phone and could send phone's output to the comp, without rooting the phone?

Comment: We can't help with dev question here, try asking on StackOverflow.  But: No, not really.  You can rapidly take screenshots and stitch them together into video (the framerate will suck), but you can't take actual video.  This YouTube video shows how to use an app that takes quick screenshots and I think puts it in a video for you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtB36BTllwY

Comment: You can't even take screenshots without root. in order to take screenshots you need to access /dev/graphics/fb0. see this post on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content/3069917#3069917 - I see there is a "permission" to read the FRAME_BUFFER but I believe it is reserved for system applications. Also, there is an open source app called Android ScreenCast (http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) that will send keystrokes from PC, but it does require root because it has to "inject" a "listener" on the device

Comment: You are looking for VNC (PC to Phone) capability the exact functionality that I am asking about in this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/any-vnc-solutions-for-an-unrooted-device).