# How can I remotely control my mobile without rooting it?

Tags: keyboard, remote-control

I have my mobile Android, iPad, typing on the small keyboards takes too long, so remotely using my keyboard is the best way for me when it comes to type something in mobile devices.

I have so far tried to use a VNC server, but they all require root, which I don't like to do.

Are there any free tools that will allow me to use my laptop to browse my Android device and type on my laptop keyboard and it will type on the Android mobile?

Comment: Any Android device that has Bluetooth functionality (probably all of them these days, aside from some cheap knock-offs) can be paired with a Bluetooth keyboard, which negates the need for remote access apps.

Comment: If you find a solution, please post it as an answer; it's [perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Putting answers in your question is confusing and makes it essentially impossible to vote on the answer. (Also, arguably, if this is a dupe of anything it may most likely be [Any VNC solutions for an unrooted device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1931) since that also specifically asks for non-root solutions; the other actually didn't so I'm re-opening at least for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it a habit to reinstall [Wifi Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan) everytime I reflash my phone.

It doesn't require root as far as I know. Basically, you set it as your default keyboard if you want to use it. Then you will see a notification and clicking that should reveal an IP address + port to you. Open that address on a browser in your computer and you should see a big text entry  box. Whatever you type on that entry box will be sent to your phone as keystrokes. So yeah, you basically use your pc/laptop keyboard as a wireless keyboard.

It doesn't let you browse the phone remotely though, but you can use it to navigate your phone (via arrow keys). And your devices also need to be on the same LAN for the IP to work.

Comment: Just used it, looks great. Atleast no requirement to make root, but i can type from my PC. Great thanks. it works

Answer (score 2):

What about [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) ? It does not need root access.